# Восстановление бинарного дерева

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы, дерево, бинарное-дерево

**Теорема:** Бинарное дерево можно однозначно восстановить имея *InOrder* **и** *PostOrder/PreOrder* последовательности, если последовательности не содержат дубликатов.

Есть идеи, каким образом можно это дело реализовать, то есть восстановить бДерево имея на входе две последовательности?

Comment: А что значит "восстановить дерево" - как может выглядеть результат? И что сам пытался делать?

Comment: Визуально увидеть его, начертить. Сижу на данный момент, ломаю голову. Мне дали два массива. In = [5, 4, 1, 6, 12, 7, 3, 8, 9, 13] и Post = [4, 5, 6, 12, 1, 3, 9, 8,13, 7] исходя из массива Post понимаю, что последний элемент будет корнем **7**, затем основываясь на этом смотря на массив In понимаю, что дерево с корнем 7 разбивается на левое поддерево [5, 4, 1, 6, 12] и правое поддерево [3, 8, 9, 13]. После этого задаюсь вопросом, каким это образом в левое поддерево залезло число 12? Ведь оно больше корня и должно быть по идеи в правой части...

Comment: А где сказано, что это дерево **поиска**? В простом бинарном дереве упорядоченность не требуется.

Comment: Спасибо, я этого не знал. У нас обычное бДерево.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно решать рекурсивно, для случая In+Post передавая аргументы `InLeft, InRight, PostRoot`

Обработать случаи `InLeft>InRight` (обрыв рекурсии) и `InLeft=InRight` - вывод листового элемента.

Найти в In элемент `In[RootIndex] = Post[PostRoot]` и вывести узловой элемент `In[RootIndex]` 
Запустить рекурсию для его поддеревьев в диапазонах левее и правее `RootIndex`,  с использованием корней поддеревьев`PostRoot-1` и `PostRoot-RootIndex`

Для случая In+Pre всё будет похоже, за исключением корня слева и подкорней правее

Answer (score 2):

Приведу ответ с одного сайта:

> Если одним префиксным/инфиксным/постфиксным — то, разумеется, нет. А
>   если двумя — дело уже интереснее (при условии, разумеется, что все
>   узлы разные). Ну, например, как восстановить дерево, которое было
>   пройдено сначала префиксно, потом постфиксно (самый сложный и
>   интересный случай). Признаюсь сразу: полное восстановление невозможно,
>   ведь ситуации «без левых сыновей» и «без правых сыновей» различить
>   нельзя.
>
> Если длины не совпадают, СТОП: некорректные данные.
>   В префиксном обходе корень в начале, в постфиксном — в конце. Если они не одинаковы, СТОП: некорректные данные.
>   Если в обходе один элемент — с этим всё понятно.
>   Второй элемент префиксного обхода — левый сын. Ищем его в постфиксном обходе.   Если он предпоследний — перед нами та самая ситуация «у дерева один сын», и рекурсивно запускаем алгоритм на обходах без корня. В противном случае выкусываем подстроки нужной длины (реально или виртуально), дважды запускаем алгоритм рекурсивно.
>
> Пример: у нас дерево.
>   a
>   /\
>   b  c
>   /\ /
>   d e f
>   Префиксный обход abdecf, постфиксный debfca. Корень a, левый сын b, он
>   в постфиксном обходе на третьей позиции. Рекурсивно запускаем алгоритм
>   на парах bde/deb и cf/fc.

Comment: Видел это. Спасибо, но здесь немного о другом.